# MySQL Master-Slave Replication "Unknown database" error

Tags: mysql, database, replication, master-slave

I'm trying to setup master-slave replication between 2 mysql servers on CentOS. Once setup if I create a database called 'fakeDB' on the master it creates it on the slave. Awesome! But if I then try to create a table on the master I get this error on the slave:

```
Last_Errno: 1049
Last_Error: Error 'Unknown database 'fakeDB'' on query. Default database: 'fakeDB'. Query: 'create table tmp (name varchar(100))'
```

But the database exists on the slave! So I then started over and created the database and tmp table on both servers. I reset everything and then tried to insert a row on the master. I then got this error on the slave:

```
Last_SQL_Errno: 1146
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Table 'fakeDB.tmp' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'fakeDB'. Query: 'insert into tmp values ('asdf')'
```

But again that database exists and so does the table on both servers. I can access them manually. Here is the variables I set in the my.cnf file on both servers.

```
server-id = 1 #set as 2 for master
log_bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
relay-log  = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
binlog_do_db = fakeDB
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you verify the database exists on the slave?  Did you run the query manually (with replication disabled) on each server and see if it succeeds?  That would be my first step to make sure the slave is working correctly.

Comment: yes. I logged-in to mysql from the command line on the slave and issued "use fakeDB". it said the database didn't exist. Then I created it on the master then tried the command again on the slave and it said it was there. But after that I couldn't get anything else to work. Creating a table or inserting a row said the database didn't exist even though it shows it's there.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I figured it out. Turns out it was something stupid. I had this option set in my configuration file on the slave:

```
lower_case_table_names=1
```

So when I created the database on the master as `fakeDB` it created it on the slave as `fakedb`. So on the slave I can issue `use fakeDB;` and it works because the command is case insensitive but then the queries issued from the master weren't so `insert into fakeDB.tmp` failed because the database name is `fakedb`.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for updating it with how you resolved it.